# Hyper-V Clipboard and Integration Services in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, virtual-machine, hyper-v, ubuntu-14.04

I have Ubuntu 14.04 running in Windows Hyper-V. I am experiencing a problem with the Clipboard (copy from host to Virtual Machine), it is not working correctly (It was not working with Ubuntu 12.04 also). I suspect that the problem lies in the Integration Services. Are they enabled by default or do I need  to enable them in Ubuntu 14.04 ? Does anyone else experience the same problem with the Clipboard Copy-Paste function ?

---

Interesting is that in the Hyper-V Clipboard the **Capture Screen(<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>)** works as seen in the image below, but **Type Clipboard Text (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>)** does not work.

```
lsmod | grep hv
```

[image: Ubuntu 14.04 running in Hyper-V image taken with clipboard screen capture]

---

I have searched the web and found only information about Ubuntu 12.04. This is what has to be done on Ubuntu 12.04: [click here](http://baudlabs.com/how-to-install-hyper-v-integration-services-in-ubuntu-12-04-lts/).  Does this also apply for Ubuntu 14.04 ? If I am correct I do not have to install something (Linux Integration Services 3.5 [here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=41554)), everything is already installed in Ubuntu, but is the procedure the same as in the above link ?

---

To enable VSS Snapshot daemon and KVP daemon use the following command:

```
# sudo apt-get update
# sudo apt-get install hv-kvp-daemon-init
```

*Ubuntu virtual machines feature distribution map* [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn531029.aspx)

Comment: here http://www.serverwatch.com/server-tutorials/installing-and-activating-hyper-v-linux-integration-services.html it's said: Ubuntu Hyper-V Integration Services have been built into Ubuntu Linux since Ubuntu 12.04

Comment: @Devid - What is the answer here? What are we supposed to do?

Comment: @AlexS in the Windows 10 Creators Update Microsoft did a lot of updates to Hyper-V. Also Ubuntu is working closer now with Microsoft. I know that they fixed the problem with the resolution, maybe they also fixed this. Sometime later I will check this and report back. Other than that I don't know about a solution that is working correctly till now.

Comment: @Devid - Don't want to rush, but almost 7 years, and I am bigging to itch for a response.... Still with (what I believe to be the latest) there is no Clipboard integration that I can get ot work...

Answer (score 19):

Since this question was asked (re ~ Ubuntu 15.04) things have progressed significantly with regards to Hyper-V & Ubuntu 18.04.1 with regards to ‘Enhanced Session Mode’.

There are two approaches currently:

**A.** New System ~~ Optimized Ubuntu Desktop images available in Microsoft Hyper-V gallery

**B.** Existing System ~~ manually configure xRDP to support ‘Enhanced Session Mode’

Here are the details:

### Option **A**)

1. In Hyper-V,  on your server & select [Quick Create]
2. In the [Create Virtual Machine] dialog, select [Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS] && then [Create Virtual Machine]
3. Then complete the standard Ubuntu installation options
4. ‘Enhanced Session Mode’ will prompt you to setup screen resolution, local resources, etc.
5. **Note/Caution ~** if you have problems using drives, then you may want to de-select the [Printers]

Here are the links to where I sourced the information:

○  [Optimised Ubuntu Desktop images available in Microsoft Hyper-V gallery](https://blog.ubuntu.com/2018/09/17/optimised-ubuntu-desktop-images-available-in-microsoft-hyper-v-gallery)

○  [Run Ubuntu virtual machines made even easier with Hyper-V Quick Create](https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2018/09/17/run-ubuntu-virtual-machines-made-even-easier-with-hyper-v-quick-create/)

### Option **B**)

1. Modify Ubuntu 18.04 to use xrdp

   1.1 Get the scripts from GitHub

   ```
   sudo apt-get update
   sudo add-apt-repository ppa:git-core/ppa
   sudo apt update; sudo apt install git
   git clone https://github.com/jterry75/xrdp-init.git ~/xrdp-init
   ```

   1.2 Make the scripts executable and run them...

   ```
   cd ~/xrdp-init/ubuntu/18.04/
   sudo chmod +x install.sh
   sudo ./install.sh
   reboot
   ```

   1.3 <*After Reboot*> Run script again to finish setting up VM

   ```
   cd ~/xrdp-init/ubuntu/18.04/
   sudo ./install.sh
   ```
2. Shutdown Ubuntu VM
3. Register Ubuntu Session ~ run this command on host PC using powershell with admin rights:

   ```
   Set-VM -VMName YourUbuntuVMNameHere -EnhancedSessionTransportType HvSocket
   ```
4. Restart VM
5. Connect/Login to XRDP from Hyper-V (note ~ enter username - must be lowercase)
6. **Note/Caution ~** if you have problems using drives, then you may want to de-select the [Printers]

---

Here is the link to where I sourced the information:

- [Windows 10: A guide how to  run Ubuntu 18.04 in Enhanced Mode in Hyper-V](https://www.tenforums.com/virtualization/107147-guide-how-run-ubuntu-18-04-enhanced-mode-hyper-v.html)

Comment: There is a better guide now available on the official repo: https://github.com/Microsoft/linux-vm-tools/wiki/Onboarding:-Ubuntu

Comment: Is there any solution for Ubuntu 20.04? I tried this without success. I do not get prompted for RDP settings at all.

Comment: For option B on Ubuntu 22, I found https://4sysops.com/archives/activate-enhanced-session-mode-for-ubuntu-vms-in-hyper-v/ describes the process well, and updated the URL they say to download to be https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Hinara/linux-vm-tools/ubuntu20-04/ubuntu/22.04/install.sh.....
And it did _not_ work. :(

Answer (score 10):

Unfortunately it doesn't work.  It looks like the correct answer here is to either:

1. SSH into your box so you can cut & paste into the your Windows SSH
   window
2. Use Oracle's VirtualBox.  Cut & Paste seems to work there.

Comment: Please stop answering user questions with install another solution.

Comment: @ZacWolf In this case, there is no solution.  It's just not supported (or at least want at the time).  The next step is to list the known work arounds.

Comment: Workarounds WITHIN the solution of the question, yes, #1 was the correct way to answer. #2 was not. Just my two cents.

Comment: Both 1 and 2 are useful

Comment: @ZacWolf it's a helpful suggestion. I am unable to get any of the other answers to work :/

Answer (score 1):

Doing an `lsmod | grep hv` on a fresh install of Ubuntu Server 14.04 shows that the Hyper-V modules are already enabled for me.

- hv_vmbus
- hv_storvsc
- hv_blkvsc
- hv_netvsc
- hv_utils

[image]

You are correct in saying that the Linux Integration Services supplied my Microsoft are not required in Ubuntu.

Comment: +1. Do you also have the problem with the Hyper-V Clipboard ? When I copy from Windows 8.1 simple text it just does not show in Ubuntu 14.04. For example the copied text "modules" from Windows shows as dddd or d or something else in Ubuntu running in Hyper-V.

Comment: I can't copy and paste between host and guest either way using Ctrl+C and Ctrl+V. Did this functionality work on 13.10?

Comment: I think that the problem lies in the Enhanced Session Mode. Although I turned it on in the options it does not work with Ubuntu. I can use the copy functionality that is Capture Screen on the guest and paste it in the host machine, But i can't use the Type Clipboard text functionality that is copy simple text from host and paste it in guest machine. I think this didn't work in Ubuntu 13.10 too,but in 13.10 the mouse scroll wheel did not work also and now in Ubuntu 14.04 it works. The thing is when I copy text it is pasting something but it is not correct. Can we report this problem somewhere ?

Comment: Having a look over Google yielded no results regarding this issue, it appears to be an ongoing issue not just in Ubuntu but in (all?) a few Linux guests in Hyper-V. Could you not resort to using VNC Server to manage the guest?

Comment: have the issue been fixed yet? I'm still suffer from it

Comment: He is correct yes, but how do we fix this? @Robula

Comment: There seems to be no fix for this issue - hyper-v seems to have no support for cut and paste between windows host OS and ubuntu 16 guest OS. This is unacceptable as a solution. Virtual box has this working out of the box...

Comment: Wow this really sucks...

Comment: Still no solution for Ubuntu 20.04 and server image.

Comment: Really @koppor that's exactly what i'm trying in Feb 2021 Ubuntu 20.04.1 (server) and Hyper-V, and I still get "Mouse input is not captured" WTF ?! ffs Microsoft, fix your programs instead of re-inventing new bs over and over.

Comment: Still broken for ubuntu 22 LTS in 2023 using their own quick create image.  MS apparently does not care about fixing this, ever